# Multi-Page React App - Robot.txt is not valid

Tags: reactjs, web, tailwind-css, robots.txt

I have a multi-page React app which contains a robot.txt. After deploying the site I have noticed an error that wasn't present during development which is hindering the SEO. The error states that the index.html syntax is not understood. In an attempted to fix this issue, I moved the file to the root of the client directory and redeployed the website, however, the issue is still present.

**Note: I have read through the documentation and everything seems to be written correctly. Any help would be great!**

**robot.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Allow: /portfolio
Allow: /purpose
Allow: /collection
Allow: /contact

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /nogooglebot/
```

**Error:**

```
1
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="description" content="..."/>
<meta name="robots" content="all"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png"/>
<link rel="fancybox-css" href="@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox/fancybox.css"/>
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/>
<title>...</title>
<script defer="defer" src="/main.a59f415f52223fd75c8e.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```